# Find subdivs within selenium in python ( selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement)

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium to access all divs which contain roster information:

```
# this returns a <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('appointment-template')
```

These divs inside this element should look like this:

```
div class="appointment-template" id="appointment-3500508">
<p class="title">Mentoruur</p>
<p class="time">11:15<span class="time-end"> - 12:15</span></p>
<ul class="facility">
    <li onclick=""
        title="HIC_Online">ONLINE
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="docent">
    <li onclick=""
        title="HANSJE">HANSJE
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="group">
    <li onclick=""
        title="ASD123">ASD123
    </li>
</ul>
```

The next thing I want to do is access values like the docent name and time values that lie within this div:

```
for div in divs:
  print(div.find_element_by_class_name('title'))
  print(div.find_element_by_class_name('time'))
```

This does not seem to work:

**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .title**

How can I use selenium to get the values like:
Mentoruur
11:15 - 12:15
Hansje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the `Mentoruur`, one should try the below css :

```
div.appointment-template p.title
```

use it like this :

```
title = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.appointment-template p.title").text
print(title)
```

to get time :

```
div.appointment-template p.time
```

**code :**

```
time = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.appointment-template p.time").text
    print(time)
```

same way you can go ahead with others.

Answer (score 1):

In order to locate element inside element it's better to use this technique:

```
for div in divs:
  print(div.find_element_by_xpath('.//p[@class="title"]'))
  print(div.find_element_by_xpath('.//p[@class="time"]'))
```

the dot `.` in front of xpath expression means "from here". This is what we need when searching inside specific parent element